# Xamarin Forms getting "markup expression missing its closing tag" error, but element has closing tag

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been working on a Xamarin forms application for awhile now and had to put it aside for about a week. Now that I'm back to it, it refuses to build because of an  error in one of the .xaml pages: Position 18:36. Markup expression is missing its closing tag. The element it is complain about looks like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding} Property"/>
```

If I take the {Binding} part out, everything build fine. What is going on here? I have tried restarting visual studio without success. Can't find anything on Google that tells me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 6):

the `Property` name needs to be inside of the curly braces

```
<Label Text="{Binding Property}"/>
```